# How to display images in pictureBox1 one by one?

Tags: c#, winforms

maybe i need a timer ?

i want that before the image is saved or after saved but to display the images one by one.
now it's just doing the loop so it's not showing the designer at all until the loop will end.

```
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace Extract_Frames
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
            {
                vFReader.Open(@"C:\Users\Chocolade 1972\Downloads\MyVid.mp4");
                for (int i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount; i++)
                {
                    Bitmap bmpBaseOriginal = vFReader.ReadVideoFrame();
                    //bmpBaseOriginal.Save(@"d:\frames\frame" + i + ".bmp");
                    pictureBox1.Image  = bmpBaseOriginal;
                    //bmpBaseOriginal.Dispose();
                }
                vFReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's working for while but after some images it's throwing exception on the line :

```
pictureBox1.Image  = bmpBaseOriginal;
```

the exception say the object is in use.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Object is currently in use

Comment: You can use a loop to load all the frames into `Images`, then use a `Timer` to display them one by one.

Comment: Just in case: [VideoSourcePlayer](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Controls_VideoSourcePlayer.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should probably be something like this:

```cs
private readonly Queue<Image> images = new Queue<Image>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
    {
        vFReader.Open(@"C:\Users\Chocolade 1972\Downloads\MyVid.mp4");

        for (var i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            images.Enqueue(vFReader.ReadVideoFrame());
        }

        // Not sure that this would be required as it might happen implicitly at the end of the 'using' block.
        vFReader.Close();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = images.Dequeue();
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

    var image = images.Dequeue();

    pictureBox1.Image = image;

    if (images.Count == 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

All the `Images` are added to a queue and then dequeued one by one. The first one is displayed as soon as the loading has completed and the rest will be displayed at regular intervals. This code displayed each `Image` once and then destroys and discards it. If you want to display them all again when you reach the last then you can use a different type of collection and wrap back to the beginning when you get to the end.

EDIT:

I may have misunderstood a little what you were asking for. This code should display the `Images` as they're generated:

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
    {
        vFReader.Open(@"C:\Users\Chocolade 1972\Downloads\MyVid.mp4");

        for (var i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, vFReader.ReadVideoFrame());
        }

        // Not sure that this would be required as it might happen implicitly at the end of the 'using' block.
        vFReader.Close();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = (Image)e.UserState;
}
```

You can ditch the `Timer` and the `Queue`. My only concern is that this may lead to an `OutOfMemoryException`. If it does, you can call explicitly call `GC.Collect` intermittently, e.g. every 100 frames.

Comment: two things : when i tried to shut down the application i got exception System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.'
 on the line : images.Enqueue(vFReader.ReadVideoFrame()); in the dowork event.  another thing in the timer tick event i'm getting exception that the pictureBox1 image is null because the line : pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); so i removed the Dispose line and it as working but should i use the dispose ?

Comment: With regards to the second issue, it sounds like you have the `Enabled` property of the `Timer` set to `true` in the designer. Given that the code is calling `Start`, I assumed that it would be clear that the `Timer` is disabled by default.

Comment: With regards to the first issue, it sounds like you're trying to exit the application before all the `Images` have been created. How many are there and how long does it take to create them? Are you wanting to start displaying them before they have all been created?

Comment: there are 60000 about images because i extract the frames from a video.  i want to display the images in the picturebox like a video while extracting the frames.

Comment: @RojerBrief, I have updated my answer with an alternative that may suit you better.